# L = {<M> | M is a TM and halts on every input after 5 steps exactly } - is L decidable?

Tags: turing-machines

in order for M to belong to L, it must halts on all inputs after 5 steps exactly. is the problem not decidable ? how can it be proved ? I could not succeed in doing a reduction from Htm as the attempt to count M(w) steps failed.

update:
apparently the language is in R. can anyone provide a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is NOT NECESSARY to read the whole input for a Turing Machine to halt.

Imagine a Turing Machine M that receives any input such that it reads anything and moves right exactly 5 times. On fifth step it reaches the accept state and halts.

M belongs to L.

Contrary to what I was thinking before, L is indeed decidable.

Consider all Σ $^5$ configurations of the first 5 cells of the tape. For each of these configurations execute 5 steps. If TM is nondeterministic execute 5 steps for all possible paths. If TM does not halt for some configuration (or execution when TM is nondeterministic) reject. Otherwise, accept.

As  Σ $^5$ is finite, L is decidable.

Comment: the simulation M on w can take more than 5 steps. you have no indication how many steps M does on w

Comment: can anyone offer a reduction from Htm maybe? or a more clear proof?

Comment: I edited the answer for clearer understanding

Comment: not convinced. it is not clear to me if you tried to show some kind of reductions or tried to decide an un-decidable language.

Comment: your M'' machine which is supposed to return accept if M(w) simulation stops after 5 steps is not correct in my opinion. because consider M that halts on w after 8 steps. in your case it will return true even though this M halts after 8 steps and not 5.

Comment: If M halts on w after 8 steps, n = 8 and M'' will reject

Comment: is M' a reduction from Htm? is that the purpose of your construction? also what do you mean by ACCEPT<M'', <M, w>> ?

Comment: M' is just an arbitrary Turing Machine. I was doing a reduction from HTM previously, but that was a mistake. ACCEPT is the acceptance problem (http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/6420/spr16/Notes/Computability/accept.html), which is also undecidable

Comment: M' is a reduction from ACCEPT

Comment: can anyone comment on \ accept this solution ?

Comment: In 5 steps a TM can only read at most 9 cells of its tape. So you need only simulate a given TM for all possible states of those 9 cells, which is finitely many. And you need only simulate for 5 steps. How is that uncomputable?

Comment: there is a theorem also which states that if a turing machine halts on all inputs smaller than 5, in 5 steps, it halts all inputs in 5 steps. so the language is in R indeed.

Comment: any other thoughts? anyone? reduction from this problem to some other problem which is in R ?

Comment: Although reading 9 cells in 5 steps doesn't seem right, the idea is there. I completely ignored the fact that there are finite configurations. I edited the answer.

Comment: @KyryloYefimenko If the tape is bidirectional, the TM can move and then read 4 times to the left or to the right and can read its initial position, so 9 cells. If the tape is unidirectional, the TM can read up to 5 cells.